# database communication with C#

Tags: c#, .net, database, sqlite, crud

As part of a new project I'm working on I need to manage a local database (sqlite) containing 2-3 tables. Because of the simplicity of the project, I'd rather not using an ORM framework. I should mention the project compiled in .NET 2.0.

What I need is:

- enabling simple operations on each table (CRUD).
- Working with POCO.

Should I just create the CRUD methods in each class? ([DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)) maybe creating a BaseDBClass enabling CRUD operations? (or is it an overhead?)

What would be the best approach considering my situation and circumstances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple projects require simple solutions. Just use ADO.NET in CRUD methods on the class or a class helper.